# Baire Category Theorem Brezis Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The theorem statement is as follows.

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space and let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of closed subsets in $X$. Assume that 
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{Int }X_n = \emptyset
> \end{align*}
>   for every $n \geq 1$. Then
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{Int } \Big(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n\Big) = \emptyset
> \end{align*}

And I don't understand the first line of the proof. It says,

> Set $O_n = X_n^c$, so that $O_n$ is open and dense in $X$ for every $n\geq 1$.

For example, we could let $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $\{X_n\} = [-n,n]$, so that $X = \cup_{1}^{\infty} X_n$, but for any $n$, we have $X_n^c = (-\infty,-n) \cup (n,\infty)$, which is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe I am misunderstanding the definition of dense? I thought if $E$ was dense in $F$, then for any point in $x \in F$ and any positive radius $r$, the ball $B(x,r)$ must contain an element of $E$. Certainly we could find a ball in $\mathbb{R}$ that contains no element of $(-\infty,-n) \cup (n,\infty)$, right?

Comment: Your $X_{n}$ do not have empty interior.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $X_n$ do not have empty interior, and as the theorem tells you (as $\mathbf R$ is complete), $\mathbf R$ cannot be written as the countable union of closed sets with empty interior (as the union would have empty interior then, and $\mathbf R$ does not).